# Using Random Numbers As Session variables

Tags: web-application, php, session-management, random

I am using randomly generated numbers as session variables to identify the sessions in a PHP application. To make further security proof what ways should I follow?

Comment: Well, I guess that you should just try to be sure that your random numbers are not predictable in any way. Meaning, you should not depend on obvious parameter such as date, time or know parameters.

Comment: I used mt_rand(). Whether its better to encrypt it.

Comment: This is really not safe, look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358691/how-is-phps-mt-rand-seeded) on StackOverflow. If you are under Linux, try to use `/dev/urandom` (a better source of randomness than `mt_rand()`).

Answer (score 3):

The best way to generate random tokens for security purposes in PHP is using [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) to obtain some random bytes, and then `bin2hex` to make them printable.

```
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
```

You can safely use `$token` for your session identifier, [CSRF tokens](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern), etc.